# Please explain the word "доступ"

Tags: перевод

Здравствуйте,

I am curious about the word "доступ", can it be used for any kind of access like mobile phone, internet, physical access to an entrance or parking space?

Спасибо большое

Comment: On many occasions it sounds like an English calque. So it's right to use "доступ" when talking about cells/internet, yet in other contexts you may find some better synonyms.

Comment: And what are those contexts?

Comment: Pretty much all the stuff about "physical access" sounds too heavy and formal, when you actually say "доступ".

Comment: According to your recommendation/doctrine it would be better to use something like: "у меня есть интернет"? and skip the доступ

Comment: Almost. As virually any person has some kind of internet access, this question may seem a bit strange. Yet questioning, for example, "У тебя есть дома интернет?" (i.e. "do you have a personal internet access point at home?") is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use that word to indicate any kind of access:

> У тебя есть ***доступ*** в интернет?

"Do you have access to Internet?"

> Мы были заперты в комнате без ***доступа*** к телефону.

"We were locked in the room without access to a telephone."

> Конфеты лежали на верхней полке, вне ***доступа*** малышей.

"Sweets lay on the top shelf, inaccessible to toddlers.